# Java searching for elements present in array

Tags: java, arrays

very new to java and oop in general. so be kind.

I have one text file which contains 10 integers, *searchkeysArray.txt*. The program creates an array named *keysArr*. I have another text file of 500 random integers, *array1.txt*. The program creates another array named *array1*.

I want to use the linearSearch method I created to search for the elements of *keysArr* within *array1* and output the index which it exist.

```
public static int linearSearch(int arr[], int x)
{  
    int size = arr.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == x)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

readFile method

```
public static int[] readFile(String file)
{
   try {
            File f = new File(file);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

            int ctr = 0;

            while (s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ctr++;
                s.nextInt();
            }
            int[] arr = new int[ctr];  //create array of that size

            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(f);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                    arr[i] = scanner2.nextInt();

            return arr;
        }
            catch(Exception e)
             {
                 return null;
             }
```

the program.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   int[] keysArr = readFile("searchkeysArray");
   int[] array1 = readFile("array17"); 
  int key = 34;

  int result = linearSearch(array1, key);
        if (result != -1)
        System.out.print("The element " +key+" is present in the array, at index " + result + " ");
        else
            System.out.print("The element " +key+" is not present in the array ");
}
```

and it outputs

```
The element 34 is present in the array, at index 359
```

which makes sense. I've manually tested numbers and (apparently) everything works fine. But I do not quite understand how I'm supposed to use keysArr as my key rather than *int x = some number*.

Want to output something like

```
The element [keysArr[0]] is present in the array, at index 359
The element [keysArr[1]] is present in the array, at index 547
  ...
The element [keysArr[4]] is not present in the array
```

and so on.
Right now keysArr just an array of 10 integers but I will eventually use hundreds..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a specific hard-coded key, such as `int key = 34`, you wish to loop over your array of keys `keysArr`. You can achieve that by using code like:

```
for (int key : keysArr) {
    int result = linearSearch(array1, key);
    if (result != -1)
        System.out.print("The element " +key+" is present in the array, at index " + result + " ");
    else
        System.out.print("The element " +key+" is not present in the array ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linear algorithm worth O(n^2) which is pretty bad if you are going to increase the number of integers.

I suggest you to load dictionary elements into a hash-map Value -> Index and iterate through the values array looking up for the position in the hashMap. This will give you O(2n) - the complexity will be linear. You'll require 2n of memory though. But in your case it is insignificant.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printResults(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, new int[]{3, 4, 7, 9});
}

public static void printResults(int dictionary[], int valuesToSearch[]){
    Map<Integer, Integer> positionsMap = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0, dictionary.length).forEach(index -> positionsMap.put(dictionary[index], index));
    Arrays.stream(valuesToSearch).mapToObj(value -> positionsMap.containsKey(value) ?
            format("Value %s is present in the array at index %s", value, positionsMap.get(value)) : format("Value %s is not present in the array", value)
    ).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```